# How to set two keys for dictionary using setdefault

Tags: python, json

I would like to set two keys for a json while maintaining multiple inner keys.  How do I do this with setdefault?

Desired Output :

```
{
    "Key1": {},
    "Key2": {
        "inner key": {
            "inner inner key": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Current code

```
import json
d = {}
d.setdefault( 'key',{}).setdefault('inner key',{})['inner inner key'] = 'value'



print json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "key": {
        "inner key": {
            "inner inner key": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what the issue is? Your output seems to resemble what you want to achieve or am I wrong?

Comment: Add a second line similar to the first but for the other key? It's really puzzling why you want to do this, though.

Comment: I am sending data to server that is expecting the two keys, I am hard coding the keys and actually appending data inside of the dictionaries.

Comment: @junnytony, my output has one top level key, while I would like two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import json
d = {}
d.setdefault( 'key1',{})
d.setdefault( 'key2',{}).setdefault('inner key',{})['inner inner key'] = 'value'


print json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're hardcoding it anyway and I don't see any reason for setdefault:

```
d = {'Key1': {}, 'Key2': {'inner key': {'inner inner key': 'value'}}}
```